# Why does python json decoder throw on a string with UTF-16 BOM?

Tags: python, json, encoding, utf-8

Digging through python json decoder implementation I have noticed that if a string is passed to `json.loads` and it starts with`\ufeff`, which is an [UTF-16 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), it raises a `JSONDecodeError`:

```
if isinstance(s, str):
    if s.startswith('\ufeff'):
        raise JSONDecodeError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)", s, 0)
```

([github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/json/__init__.py#L336))

[RFC3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) (the UTF-8 one) states two cases when UTF-16 BOM should be forbidden, but none of them seem to apply to JSON:

> o  A protocol SHOULD forbid use of U+FEFF as a signature for those
> textual protocol elements that the protocol mandates to be always
> UTF-8, the signature function being totally useless in those
> cases.
>
> o  A protocol SHOULD also forbid use of U+FEFF as a signature for
> those textual protocol elements for which the protocol provides
> character encoding identification mechanisms, when it is expected
> that implementations of the protocol will be in a position to
> always use the mechanisms properly.  This will be the case when
> the protocol elements are maintained tightly under the control of
> the implementation from the time of their creation to the time of
> their (properly labeled) transmission.

[RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) (the JSON one) says that:

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.  The
> default    encoding is UTF-8, and JSON texts that are encoded in UTF-8
> are    interoperable in the sense that they will be read successfully
> by the    maximum number of implementations; there are many
> implementations    that cannot successfully read texts in other
> encodings (such as UTF-16 and UTF-32).

So it seems to me that UTF-16 should be allowed. So why does Python raise here then? Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up which RFC is for UTF-8 and which is for JSON. Also, Python 3 `str` represents encoding-independent Unicode.

Comment: After more reading it became more clear. The main reason for python json parser to refuse a BOM it correctly stated in accepted answer - spec allows it, so this parser does it.

What got me confused is that I was thinking that there are two BOMs, UTF-8 and UTF-16, and parser refused UTF-16 one while stating that it is refusing UTF-8 one. In fact there's only one BOM, U+FEFF, the \xef\xbb\xbf version is just a UTF-8 encoding of it. 

So the logic behind this code as I understand it now is: [continued]

Comment: [cont.]: if a string starts with BOM, then it must be unstripped UTF-8 one, because if it was the UTF-16 one, it would have been stripped on read. If it survived, then the bytes that originated passed string were encoded in UTF-8 and decode without stripping BOM. This is why exception also tells to "decode using utf-8-sig".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [currently most recent JSON RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-8.1):

> Implementations MUST NOT add a byte order mark (U+FEFF) to the beginning of a networked-transmitted JSON text.  In the interests of interoperability, implementations that parse JSON texts MAY ignore the presence of a byte order mark rather than treating it as an error.

Similar language also appears in [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-8.1).

A JSON implementation is not required to accept a byte order mark. Python's implementation does not. If you want to pass JSON with a byte order mark to Python's JSON parser, the BOM should be removed in an earlier processing phase.

Comment: This seems like a mistake in the specs to me. The formal definition of `U+FEFF` isn't a byte order mark, it's a [`ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm). JSON should treat it like any other whitespace.

Comment: @MarkRansom: JSON specifically [singles out](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#section-2) four whitespace characters as permitted in "insignificant whitespace": space, horizontal tab, line feed, and carriage return. Other whitespace outside of a string is an error.

Comment: Yes it does, and my belief is that the list of whitespace is unnecessarily restrictive. Why bother to be Unicode based if you're only going to use the ASCII subset of it?

Comment: Thank you. This answers the question itself, but at first I was still confused. Actually your comment under original question about encoding-independent Unicode helped to clear things up much more! :)